# Selecting pseudo-element with TestCafe

Tags: testing, css-selectors, automated-tests, pseudo-element, testcafe

I feel like this is something simple but I have some code like on the page:

```
<input type="radio">::after</input>
<input type="radio"></input>
```

How do I select the `input` with the `::after` psudo-element in Testcafe?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At present, this feature is not implemented. Track the https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2813 issue in the TestCafe Github repository to be informed about our progress.